# Python: Dynamically create variables using currently inspected item in for loop

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm wondring if there is any way to create new variables from the name of the currently inspected item in a for loop:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
for item in list:
    item_new = 1

print a_new 
print b_new
print c_new
```

What i want this to outputis:

```
1
1
1
```

Edit:
Ouch, ok, point taken :P

Knew a dict would work in this instance, just wanted to check if the method above was viable. Apparently not!

Comment: Please don't do that

Comment: You should use a `dict` instead.

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but read [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) first.

Answer (score 4):

You should not do this with variables. A dictionary is what you are looking for:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
variables = {}
for item in list:
    variables[item] = 1

print variables["a"]
print variables["b"]
print variables["c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals) function returns a reference to a `dict` where you can inspect local variables, and each key represents the local variable name as an string:

```
>>> locals()
{'a': 2, 'b': 9, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> var = "Some text"
>>> locals()
{'var': 'Some text', 'a': 2, 'b': 9, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

There is also the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#globals) function that you can also use not only to inspect global variables but also to create new global variables dynamically:

```
>>> globals()['ZZ'] = 123
>>> ZZ
123
```

But **please**, don't do this. This program is unmainteinable. Use a normal `dict` to create custom elements with your code. This program is way far more readable and maintainable:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
d = {}
for item in list:
    d[item] = 1

print d['a'] 
print d['b']
print d['c']
```

Comment: The documention for [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals) specifically says "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new variables, a dictionary seems like a better approach.

Also, it's best to not use the variable name `list`, because that is already the name of a function.

```
L = ["a", "b", "c"]
d = {}
for item in L:
    d["{}_new".format(item)] = 1

print d["a_new"]
print d["b_new"]
print d["c_new"]
```